# Is there some trick to check for unbalanced parentheses?

Tags: brackets, spelling

Good evening!

I was just about to hand in my master's thesis, when I realized that I had a case of $(...(...)$ in a formula. As a consequence, I would be very interested to find similar instances of unbalanced parantheses, but I don't really know how.

Unfortunately, this is one of the problems where regular expressions cannot be applied, so I would really like to hear some tips and tricks you may know to spot errors like these.

Comment: Some classical manual tools: a. highlighting via editor, b. counting opening and closing ([{ ... c. indenting (structured programming) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style . // If you already HAVE misbalancing, you'll recognize at compile time. Most often it won't compile, sometimes it does AND it generates a strange "print".